# How to fix the script issue in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to do JMeter testing in Mac and I have recorded a script in JMeter and when tried to playback the script, it doesn't run and gives the below error

```
2019-04-15 11:36:04,484 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2019-04-15 11:36:04,489 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2019-04-15 11:36:04,489 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2019-04-15 11:36:04,690 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2019-04-15 11:36:04,690 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 5 threads for group Thread Group.
2019-04-15 11:36:04,690 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2019-04-15 11:36:04,691 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=5 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2019-04-15 11:36:04,692 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2019-04-15 11:36:04,691 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2019-04-15 11:36:04,692 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2019-04-15 11:36:04,692 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2019-04-15 11:36:04,692 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2019-04-15 11:36:04,895 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2
2019-04-15 11:36:04,896 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-2
2019-04-15 11:36:04,896 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-2
2019-04-15 11:36:05,096 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-3
2019-04-15 11:36:05,097 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-3
2019-04-15 11:36:05,097 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-3
2019-04-15 11:36:05,294 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-4
2019-04-15 11:36:05,294 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-4
2019-04-15 11:36:05,294 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-4
2019-04-15 11:36:05,495 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-5
2019-04-15 11:36:05,496 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-5
2019-04-15 11:36:05,496 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-5
2019-04-15 11:36:05,496 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2019-04-15 11:36:05,496 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Comment: there is no error in this log.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you get any solution? There is no error but, it does not hit the server.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in your log.

Usually after recording, there is some correlation work to do.

First check you added a HTTP Cookie Manager  then check:

- header
- parameter
- ids that change between 2 recordings

Answer (score 1):

just go to thread group and ptut infinite to 1